# How can I use mongoose functions inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Is there a way I can use mongoose function inside a forEach loop like this example ? making use of the counter and reach the reachable line

```
   idsArray.forEach((itemId,i) =>{

        Place.findById(itemId,(err,item)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("error")
            }
            idsArray[i] = {item.id}; // unreachable
        })
    })
```

I read about Async but I couldn't know the way to achieve it through it

Comment: you should return inside the `if (error)` statement, that could be one of the reasons you can't access to item.id. Maybe the query is failing but as you are not returning it keeps going even if there it was an error and item is undefined or null

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler: map the elements with db promises, then wait for all of them:

```
var promises= idsArray.map((itemId,i) =>{
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    Place.findById(itemId,(err,item)=>{
        if(err){
           return reject(new Error("some"));
        }
        resolve(item);
    })
 });
});

Promises.all(promises).then(function(arr){
  console.log(arr);//all results
},function(err){
 throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Jonas w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) has the correct answer, but I'd like to show some minor variations, and the comment-area is not very useful.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');  // I like bluebird

// Using exec you get fully-fledged promises from the get-go.
var promises = idsArray.map( itemId => {
  return Place.findById(itemId).exec();
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then( arr => { console.log(arr); } )
  .catch( err => { throw err; } );
```

Comment: This is actually the better way. I dont use mongoose so i didnt know of .exec() ... +1