# Mongoose async call inside a loop with async library

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, async.js

I just start using nodejs/mongoose and I think I have a classical async problem. Could someone guide me how to fix this async problem?

I have this function "getAreasRoot" and inside I have a loop to populate children with the result of another async function. How can I fix it with the async library?

```
areaSchema.statics.getAreasRoot = function(cb: any) {
    let self = this;
    return self.model("Area").find({ parentId: null }, function(err: any, docs: any){
        docs.forEach(function(doc: any){
            doc.name = "Hi " + doc.name;
            doc.children = self.model("Area").getAreasChildren(doc._id, function(err: any, docs: any){});
        })
        cb(err, docs);
    });
};

areaSchema.statics.getAreasChildren = function(id: any, cb: any) {
    return this.model("Area").find({ parentId: null }).exec(cb);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use mongoose functions inside a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569770/how-can-i-use-mongoose-functions-inside-a-for-loop)

Comment: @KevinB Not really a duplicate if the OP is asking how to use it with async.js. None of the answers provided uses async.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 tasks: get the roots and then get the children using the roots.

If I were to do this using async.js, I would use a combination of [async.waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) and [async.mapSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries). We use `.waterfall` because we want to pass the results from the first task to the second task. We use `.mapSeries` because we want to alter each root area with its name and children.

```
areaSchema.statics.getAreasRoot = function (cb) {
    let self = this;
    async.waterfall([
        // every task has a callback that must be fired at least/most once
        // to tell that the task has finished OR when an error has occurred
        function getRoots (cb1) {
            self.find({ parentId: null }, cb1);
        },
        function getChildren (roots, cb2) {
            async.mapSeries(roots, function (root, cb3) {
                // inside this block, we want to fire the innest callback cb3 when 
                // each iteration is done OR when an error occurs to stop .mapSeries
                self.find({ parentId: root._id }, function (err, children) {
                    // error: stop .mapSeries
                    if (err)
                        return cb3(err);
                    root.name = "Hi " + root.name;
                    root.children = children;
                    // done: send back the altered document
                    cb3(null, root);
                });
            // the last argument is fired when .mapSeries has finished its iterations
            // OR when an error has occurred; we simply pass the inner callback cb2
            }, cb2) 
        }
    // the last argument is fired when .waterfall has finished its tasks
    // OR when an error has occurred; we simply pass the original callback cb
    ], cb);
};
```

To use it

```
Area.getAreasRoot(function (err, areas) {
    console.log(err, areas);
})
```

**Aside**

Mongoose operations are asynchronous, so

```
doc.children = self.model("Area").getAreasChildren(...)
```

is not correct as you are returning a Promise opposed to the actual documents.

**Also**

You *might* be able to simplify your logic with [virtual population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) or [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Perfect documented answer

Comment: Is there any easy way to get also the children of the children and so on?

Comment: @Michalis I had this feeling you were going to ask this. Unfortunately, I do not know nor think it would be a good idea to do with async.js. You might want to rethink your schema. [This](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-tree-structures/) might be helpful.